# High server load detected and server automatically stopped

Tags: ubuntu

For the last month, my VPS has been experiencing spikes in server load, and the server shuts down as a result and I have to restart it manually.

This doesn't happen everyday, but it has happened at least once every 2-3 days for the last month. The spike happens sometime at night, usually between 12-3 am.

Last night at 12:28 am, the server load was 25, 65, 125 (15 min avg, 5 min avg, 1 min avg). That's when the server shuts down. A minute before that, the server load was normal (less than 5 for all three averages). The memory and incoming/outgoing traffic are normal.

I could not diagnose the problem. I tried to store the output of the command "ps aux" every second for the last 24 hours, but I didn't find any irregularities.

I think that a process might be spawning itself in a loop to infinity. It happens so fast that the server shuts down without being able to log any irregularities.

How can I find out what happens? I'm not very experienced with system administration.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10. It's a web server. I have Apache and MySQL installed on it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific enough question but I can try and help anyway.

Have you looked at what is causing the crash?  We ran into the issue where bots were attacking our server and causing it to be overloaded.  This can happen on things like WordPress and Drupal.  Sometimes the DOS attacks were enough to crash the server.  Check your access logs, and see if the volume increases around the time of the crash, especially to login pages.  There are multiple things you can do if this is the case, such as install fail2ban, mod_evasive, Cloudflare, IP Tables Rate Limiting, etc...

You may also be running out of RAM, and you may be able to enable swap space as overflow.  If you do use swap, make sure you find out what is flooding your RAM, so you can make sure you don't use it in the future (swap is slow, and you should fit your application into the available RAM you have).

There may also be a bad update you had on your server, this happened to a lot of people on AWS Amazon Linux back in February/March after a bad update was pushed.  Every 24 hours or so the kernel would panic.  This may be the case with an Ubuntu update.

There may be a failing host on your VPS, but that may not be the case since some companies change your host when you restart or if you stop/start an instance.

There maybe a configuration problem as well with Apache/MySQL, especially involving DB caching on MySQL or Prefork (if configured this way) on Apache.

There are a gazillion reasons for what could cause your server to fail, but maybe one of these suggestions can help you.

Comment: Thanks David. At first, I thought it might be someone attacking the website by DoS, but the stats I get from my VPS provider shows no incoming traffic when this happens. I also thought it might be the RAM, but according to the stats, I've been using 50% of the available RAM. I thought it might be a malicious cron job, but there are no crons running that shouldn't be running.

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose the problem, and not being a sys admin, it is somehow difficult for me pinpointing the problem. Is there a tool you recommend that can help me diagnose the problem? By the way, the server hasn't had a problem for the past 4 days. It seems to be completely random when the server crashes.